# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension when installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm on windows and trying to install rails. but I get the following error message:

```
Z:\AlexL\My Documents\rails>gem install rails
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150211-3312-5ie7vd.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/js
on-1.8.2/gem_make.out
```

Ruby version is:
ruby 1.9.3p484

I've got this devkit installed DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx
 in this folder:

C:\Ruby193\DevKit\

Not sure what else is wrong?

Comment: do not user Windows with ruby :) seriously, install Ubuntu on Virtual Machine

Answer (score 0):

Looks the same as the issue being discussed [here](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/977).

Apparently, there is a problem with Ruby 1.9.3 and newer RubyGems versions on Windows machines. Their quick-fix solution was to downgrade to an earlier version of RubyGems.

```
gem update --system 1.8.29
```

Once you have done that, confirm that `gems -v` returns `1.8.29` and try your command again.

Otherwise, you can upgrade to Ruby 2.X, which should also resolve this problem.